# Identify the cell type and replace entry with default text/value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet where the user enters loads of data in a column.

I want to run a script that resets the user-entered data to defaults.

However, they need a different default value depending on the type of data that can be entered:

- Dropdown add "Choose" this is one of the options in all dropdowns
- Text entry see below
- Checkmark/tick box remove the tick/checkmark

Some cells in the column have formulas, and I want it to do nothing for these.

For the text entry, I have three text types, so ideally would like them to have different defaults

- date - show "add date" in cell
- text - clear the text
- number - enter zero

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Description**

This may not be all inclusive for DataValidation but it will handle the items you mention above.  Note that the check for Date has to be done before number.

I've created a small test sheet with each value type.

I leave it up to you to put the values back.

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");
    let range = sheet.getDataRange();
    range.uncheck();
    let values = range.getValues();
    values.forEach( row => {
        let value = row[0];
        if( value instanceof Date ) {
          row[0] = "add date";
        }
        else if( !isNaN(value) ) {
          row[0] = 0;
        }
        else if( typeof value === "string" ) {
          row[0] = "";
        }
      }
    );
    let rules = range.getDataValidations();
    rules.forEach( (row,iRow) => { row.forEach( (cell,iCell) => { if( ( cell != null ) && ( cell.getCriteriaType() != SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX ) ) values[iRow][iCell] = "Choose" } ) } );
    let formulas = range.getFormulas();
    formulas.forEach((row,iRow) => { row.forEach( (cell,iCell) => { if( cell !== "" ) values[iRow][iCell] = cell } ) } );
    console.log(values);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

11:42:43 AM Notice  Execution started
11:42:44 AM Info    [ [ '' ], [ 0 ], [ 'add date' ], [ 'Choose' ], [ '=A2' ], [ 0 ] ]
11:42:44 AM Notice  Execution completed

**References**

- [Range.uncheck()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#uncheck)
- [Range.getDataValidations()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdatavalidations)
- [Range.getFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas)

Comment: Thank you TheWizEd it works well I'm working my way through your code and learning a lot, including how little I understand but we all have to start somewhere.

Comment: If this answeres you question, please mark it as the answer so other who have similar question can find a possible solution.  Thanks.